# composer install failing for unknown reason in travis-ci

Tags: docker, composer-php, travis-ci

I'm running a `composer install` after a `docker-compose up` and am unable to get the CI process to continue.  All of the output shows the install was successful except for travis' interpretation of the output.  See https://travis-ci.org/BibleBowl/account/builds/125161543#L1454

Is there something I can do to show more verbose output?

Comment: The command `docker-compose up` already installs your composer dependencies - why installing them a second time? It may be a problem with file access, so adding more verbosity to the second command is an idea.

Comment: `-v` or `-V` or `-vv` or `-VV`?